# How to calculate the distance between all atoms in a PDB file and create a distance matrix from that

Tags: python, biopython, distance-matrix

I would like to calculate the distances between all atom in a pdb file and then create a distance matrix from the result of the PDB.

I currently have all the x, y and z coordinates but I am struggling to to do this distance calculation for all atoms.

distance = sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2+(z1-z2)^2)

For example:

Distance between Atom 1 and Atom 2 ,3 ,4...

Distance between Atom 2 and Atom 3, 4, 5...

And so forth for every Atom in the PDB file. I'm new to coding so any method to achieve the end result would be great.

pdb file in question - https://files.rcsb.org/download/6GCH.pdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering your code, you can:

```
x_y_z_ = list()
...
         for atom in residue:
            x = (atom.coord[0]) 
            y = (atom.coord[1])
            z = (atom.coord[2])
            x_y_z_.append([x,y,z])
...
x_y_z_ = np.array(x_y_z_)
print( pairwise_distances(x_y_z_,x_y_z_) )
```

and them use pairwise_distances from sklearn, like:

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
import numpy as np

x_y_z_ = np.array([[120,130,123],
    [655,123,666],
    [111,444,333],
    [520,876,222]])

print( pairwise_distances(x_y_z_,x_y_z_) )

out:

[[  0.         762.31423967 377.8584391  852.24233643]
[762.31423967   0.         714.04901793 884.51681725]
[377.8584391  714.04901793   0.         605.1660929 ]
[852.24233643 884.51681725 605.1660929    0.        ]]
```

Comment: I think this is close to what I want but I'm not sure if that addition to the code.  Does this:       distance between 2 atoms  = sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2+(z1-z2)^2).

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html

Comment: by default it is euclidean distance, which is **sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2+(z1-z2)^2)**

Comment: I managed to get the code to work thank you very much @Guinther Kovalski !!

Comment: Just a quick side question, is there any method to only print one half of the distance matrix, instead of printing it twice (once on the top and once on the bottom half).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have all the coordinates in a `numpy.array`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

coords = np.random.rand(N_atoms, 3)  # mimicking your 3-D coordinates.

dis_mat = distance_matrix(coords, coords)
```

The `dis_mat`, a `N_atoms * N_atoms` matrix, is what you want.

Edits:
The above is to calculating the density matrix between **two different sets** of coordinates. If you want the **pair-wise** distance matrix of the **same set** of 3-D coordinates, try this:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

dis_mat = squareform(pdist(coords))
```

Comment: The `pdist` function gives you the half matrix only. The `squareform` function turns it to a full square matrix.